# ¿Como puedo hacer un select con join en php con base de datos de oracle correctamente?

Tags: php, sql, oracle

Estoy desarrollando una aplicacion web de hospital y tengo una función para rescatar datos de oracle con una sentencia sql que hace join con tablas y utiliza alias, el resultado que deberia dar la funcion es un array asociativo con todos los campos y sus respectivos datos, pero solo me entrega null. El codigo es el siguiente:

```
    public function datos_generales_paciente($run){
    $this->getConnection();
    $run_mayus = strtoupper($run);
    $sql ="SELECT PA.NOMBRES_PACIENTE as nombres_paciente,PA.APELLIDO_PATERNO_PACIENTE || ' ' || PA.APELLIDO_MATERNO_PACIENTE as apellidos_paciente,PA.RUN_PACIENTE as run_paciente,ROUND((SYSDATE - PA.COD_FECHA_NACIMIENTO)/365.3) as edad_paciente,SE.NOMBRE_SEXO as sexo,PM.COD_GRUPO_SANGUINEO as gp FROM CFS_PACIENTE PA JOIN CFS_SEXO SE ON (PA.COD_SEXO = SE.COD_SEXO) JOIN CFS_PORTAFOLIO_MEDICO PM ON (PA.RUN_PACIENTE = PM.RUN_PACIENTE) JOIN CFS_DETALLE_ALERGIA_PORTAFOLIO DAP ON (DAP.COD_PORTAFOLIO = PM.COD_PORTAFOLIO) WHERE (PA.RUN_PACIENTE = '$run_mayus')";

    $stid = oci_parse($this->connection, $sql);
    oci_execute($stid);

    //Llena un array con los campos devueltos por oracle bbdd
    $datos_generales = array();
    while ($row = oci_fetch_array($stid, OCI_ASSOC+OCI_RETURN_NULLS)){
        $datos_generales[] = $row;
    }
    oci_free_statement($stid);
    $this->closeConnection();
    return $datos_generales;
}
```

Las lineas de codigo $this->getConnection() y $this->getConnection() funcionan correctamente.

Comment: Verificaste que la consulta sql si esta devolviendo algo? Intenta con un echo $sql; para ver si es asi.

Comment: Revisa el valor de `oci_error($this->connection)` después de `oci_parse()`.

Comment: En principio verifica que tu consulta si este arrojando información y no tenga errores